# How do I only select unique records from firestore .onSnapshot

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

Because of the limitations in firebase compound queries I have to use the following to get all of the documents I need.

```js
    for ( let i = 0; i < filters.dateRange.length; i ++) {
    const query = this.dataSvc.getAllItineraries()
    .where('jobCode', '==', filters.jobCode)
    .where('dateRange', 'array-contains', filters.dateRange[i]);
    query.onSnapshot(itineraryListSnapshot => {
          itineraryListSnapshot.forEach(snap => {
          this.allItineraries.push({
            id: snap.id,
            startDate: snap.data().startDate,
            endDate: snap.data().endDate,
            userId: snap.data().userId
          });
        });
      });
    }
```

The problem is that it's duplicating records as it iterates over the date_range.  I need a way to only pull in unique records based on the id.  Or, after the query is finished, remove the duplicate IDs.

Is there a way to do that?

Or is there a way to only display unique records in the UI from the HTML?

Comment: Are you asking if there a way other than filtering the duplicates in your own code after all of the queries complete?

Comment: Either way would suffice.  If I could filter the data with the firestore query would be best.  But, if I could remove the duplicate IDs after retrieving the data that would also work.  Or if I could just hide the duplicate records in the UI.

Comment: You will have to do it in your code.  Use `snap.id` as the unique identifier.

Comment: Do you have an example?  Also, one issue I have is .onSnapshot doesn't return a promise.  So I'm not sure how to wait until the operation is done before filtering the data...there's no .then() function.

Comment: I guess the better question is, where could I do this in my code?  The problem with .onSnapshot is that it doesn't have a way to wait until the operation is finished.  I supposed I could copy the content of the data from firebase and create an operation that looks for duplicate ID's.  But whenever I try to do an operation on the results it's null in the console.log because I haven't found a way to until the operation has finished.

Comment: If you don't need a "live" view of your data, then use get() instead of onSnapshot() for a single query.

Comment: Yea, I need the live view

Comment: Then those queries will never complete, and you will need to deal with that fact.

Comment: @DougStevenson I took your advice and used .get instead and it returns unique records.  My question is, why?  With Snapshop I had to add code to filter unique ID's but I don't have to with .get.  I also noticed that with .get() it takes longer to return the data.